# Erro MongoDB - geoNear "no geo indices"

Tags: node.js, rest, mongodb, get, mongoose

Para fazer o get de uma base de dados MongoDB uso o seguinte código:

```
    router.get('/multibancos', function(req, res, next){
    MB.aggregate().near({
      near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [parseFloat(req.query.lng) , parseFloat(req.query.lat)] },
                  distanceField: "dist.calculated",
                  maxDistance: 100000,
                  spherical: true
      }).then(function(mb){
          res.send(mb);
      }).catch(next);
  });
```

e chamo com o seguinte link:

```
localhost:4000/api/multibancos/?lng=80&lat=-20
```

Acontece que me devolve o erro:

```
    {
    "error": "geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"no geo indices for geoNear\" }"
}
```

Comment: tente executar esse comando no mongo: `db.ensureIndex({ loc: '2dsphere' });` e depois executar a query novamente

Comment: executar antes do "router.get('...')" ?

Comment: No mongo shell mesmo @SaPires